# Error Recyclerview view Holder on private access adapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

this is my recycler adapter class where I want to add a comments list but it shows me this error I also make a custom recycler view of another adapter class which is for Exo player but it doesn't give me any issue.

```
public class commentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<commentListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<commentsListModel> feedModels;
boolean isExpanded = false;

public commentListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<commentsListModel> feedModels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feedModels = feedModels;
}

public commentListAdapter() {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_comments_list, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    commentsListModel model = feedModels.get(position);
    holder.userName.setText(model.getUserName());
    holder.userComments.setText(model.getUserComments());
    holder.userLikes.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (!isExpanded) {
            holder.userLikes.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(holder.userLikes, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Red)));
            isExpanded = true;
        } else {
            holder.userLikes.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(holder.userLikes, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Grey)));
            isExpanded = false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedModels.size();
}


private static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView userComments, userName;
    ImageView userLikes;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        userLikes = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_video_comments_user_like);
        userComments = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_video_user_comments_details);
        userName = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_video_comment_user_name);
    }
    }
    }
```

this is an issue I have faced in it.

> commentListAdapter.java:19: error: MyViewHolder has private access in commentListAdapter
> public class commentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<commentListAdapter.MyViewHolder>

I don't know why this happen kindly guide me about this issue

Comment: The error is self explanatory Remove `private` from `class MyViewHolder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the documentation on [Visibility of class members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), which should hopefully give you a better overview.

The specific problem you have here is that you have declared `MyViewHolder` private which restricts access to it outside of `commentListAdapter`.

Therefore the statement `return new MyViewHolder(view);` is perfectly valid because the access is in `commentListAdapter`.

However the line `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<commentListAdapter.MyViewHolder>`
is not, because you are now intending for your `MyViewHolder` class to be used outside of `commentListAdapter`.

---

As a side note, I think it would he helpful to take a look at some Java coding conventions for your class naming: [Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).